# Revert a make install due to installing PCL before VTK

Tags: 18.04, make, software-uninstall, cmake

I'm following the steps of a repository and to sample some dataset, PCL and VTK are needed. I had a [lot of issues before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407383/cant-fix-broken-dependencies-but-cant-spot-exactly-why) regarding broken packages and had to delete and install again Ubuntu (18.04), so I am being extra careful from now on. According to the instructions provided:

```
git clone https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl.git
cd pcl
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make -j4
sudo make install
```

And afterwards:

```
tar -xzvf VTK-8.2.0.zip  #I could not run this command so I just right clicked, uncompress. Can this be the problem?
cd VTK-8.2.0/
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make -j4
sudo make install
```

All fine. Afterwards, in the script folder I need to run (sample):

```
cd sample
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make
```

I get the following in this last step, `make`:

```
/home/mk/PCN-PyTorch/sample/mesh_sampling.cpp:39:10: fatal error: pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h: No such file or directory
 #include <pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>
```

Doing some [research about this missing pcl_visualizer.h](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/2711), in the PCL github issues, they state the following, making me think that I can just uninstall both, and run them again but reverse order (First VTK and then PCL makes):

> How did you obtain your PCL? It seems like it was built without
> visualization module, which is of course needed to build "PCL
> visualizer" tutorial.

Upon researching on "how to revert make safely", I see that with [make uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87111/if-i-build-a-package-from-source-how-can-i-uninstall-or-remove-completely):

```
sudo make uninstall
```

> if the app was installed as root.
>
> But this will work only if the developer of the package has taken care
> of making a good uninstall rule.

I also saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439950/whats-the-opposite-of-make-install-i-e-how-do-you-uninstall-a-library-in-li):

> that make clean removes any intermediate or output files from your
> source / build tree. However, it only affects the source / build tree;
> it does not touch the rest of the filesystem and so will not remove
> previously installed software.
>
> If you're lucky, running make uninstall will work. It's up to the
> library's authors to provide that, however; some authors provide an
> uninstall target, others don't.

PCL and VTK are well known libraries, so I think there shoulnd't be any issue. But this **"IF YOU ARE LUCKY"** worries me.

Comment: It doesn't look that you need to revert anything. You can install again with no problem.

Comment: Does that mean I don´t even need to do `make uninstall`? Just `make clean` on PCL, VTK and the sample directory of the model, and then run again the instructions commands provided in the proper order (VTK, PCL and sample folder of project)? @Pilot6

Comment: Even `make clean` is not mandatory. You had a build error and nothing was built, so noting is installed.

Comment: From my understanding, PCL and VTK were built properly, so I should make clean all, and start with VTK. But if not, what procedure do you recommend? (Sorry if it seems obvious, I really do not want to mess anything up again) @Pilot6

Comment: Do you really need to "revert" anything? My expectation would be that it's sufficient to rebuild pcl making sure that it picks up the now-installed vtk

Comment: Sure! I don't know! That is why I'm asking! I am scared of screwing packages. If I just have to rebuild (do the PCL process again) now that VTK is installed, I will try! Thank you for the advices! @steeldriver

Comment: Well nothing in life is certain - however "well behaved" source packages default to installing into `/usr/local` so interaction with deb packages is minimized. (If you look in the pcl build directory's `CMakeCache.txt` file you should see something like `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr/local`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with PCL's process of building and compiling after VTK's, and it did not fix the issue.

The solution was to delete PCL's build directory, build and compile again PCL:

```
cd pcl
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make -j4
sudo make install
```

As mentioned by Users @Pilot6 and @steeldriver , there was no need to 'revert' anything or 'uninstall'.